# Those who believe that Baptism is necessary for salvation explain the apparent uncertainty with scripture please?

Tags: exegesis, soteriology, baptism

My questions relates to whether baptism a necessary act for salvation, according to the Bible, or whether its actual meaning has been misunderstood.

'Baptism' actually means, immersing in water. In other words, having a wash, shower or cleanliness rather than an act of salvation.

[John 8:32] And ye shall know the truth, and the truth shall make you free

I feel that the meaning of baptism has been misunderstood and misinterpreted by the church fathers of different denominations. These days it has become more of a tradition than actual purpose of the teachings.

Paul writes, [1 Corinthians 13-17] 13 Is Christ divided? was Paul crucified for you? or were ye baptized in the name of Paul? 14 I thank God that I baptized none of you, but Crispus and Gaius; 15 Lest any should say that I had baptized in mine own name. 16 And I baptized also the household of Stephanas: besides, I know not whether I baptized any other. 17 For Christ sent me not to baptize, but to preach the gospel: not with wisdom of words, lest the cross of Christ should be made of none effect.

Now, the question to ask is, whose Gospel was Paul preaching? Was it his own Gospel or Christ's?

[Romans 2:16] on that day when, according to my gospel, God judges the secrets of men by Christ Jesus.
[Roman 16:25] Now to him that is of power to stablish you according to my gospel, and the preaching of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery, which was kept secret since the world began,
[2 Timothy 2:8] Remember that Jesus Christ of the seed of David was raised from the dead according to my gospel:

List of Questions:

1. 4300 years of human history before John the Baptist, Nobody was Baptised?
2. How did they make it to heaven?
3. If the Baptism was a way of Salvation, but Jesus did not need to be saved or wash away his sins, he did not commit any sin, so why was he Baptised?
4. Did Jesus need to repent?
5. What about the thief on the cross?

[Luke 23:39-43] 39 One of the criminals who hung there hurled insults at him: “Aren’t you the Messiah? Save yourself and us!” 40 But the other criminal rebuked him. “Don’t you fear God,” he said, “since you are under the same sentence? 41 We are punished justly, for we are getting what our deeds deserve. But this man has done nothing wrong.” 42 Then he said, “Jesus, remember me when you come into your kingdom.[d]” 43 Jesus answered him, “Truly I tell you, today you will be with me in paradise.”

If baptism saves you, then doesn't that mean we need to rely on the church who baptizes us to save us?

Comment: This seems like a great question, but unfortunately it is a bad fit for this site.  This question seems to be intended to elicit discussion and to seek the truly correct interpretation of scripture, but that is not the purpose of this site.  We commonly refer to such questions "truthiness questions".  This site, rather, is aimed at seeking the official doctrinal stances by various denominations on such topics rather than seeking which denomination's interpretation is the correct one.

Comment: Anyway, I hope that a negative reaction to your first question doesn't turn you off to our site.  Sometimes it can just take a little while to learn the ropes, as it were.  Welcome to the site and I hope to see you around in the future.

Comment: A couple of things to point out.  John prophesied that Jesus would baptize with the Holy Spirit (and with fire).  While He did baptize in water as well, or at least His disciples did, John's baptism was a shadow of what was to come.  Salvation is not by baptism, but by faith.

Comment: Thanks @Narnian for the comment. You may want to have a look at this [James 2:17-24,26] "24 You see that a man is justified by works and not by faith alone. 26 For as the body apart from the spirit is dead, so faith apart from works is dead."

Comment: Your question can only be answered if you designate a specific denomination since there is widespread disagreement about the necessity of Baptism, and even the meaning of Baptism. Some denominations feel it is required for Salvation while others do not, there are even some denominations that believe that Baptism is required at birth to cleanse original sin. There is also wide disagreement on what baptism really includes. some feel only water while others feel both water and fire, and several in between.

Comment: @zagoo2000 I've read that already.  Thank you.  Ephesians 2:8-9 affirms that is by faith, not works.  It is by faith alone, but not by a faith that is alone.  A genuine faith produces a change that leads to works.

Comment: As Bye and Bruised Reed have pointed out, the best way to fix your question to bring it inline with the policies of this site would be to specify a specific denomination or theology.  For instance, rather than trying to seek the correct interpretation of the scriptures, you could ask, "How do those who believe that Baptism is required for salvation explain the apparent contradiction with such and such scripture".

Comment: "4300 years of human history before John the Baptist, Nobody was Baptised (so) How did they make it to heaven?" 4300 years before Jesus was born, nobody believed in Jesus, so how did they make it to heaven?  Your premise is faulty. Following your rabbit trail will just lead you to atheism.

Comment: "If baptism saves you, then doesn't that mean we need to rely on the church who baptizes us to save us?" If belief in Jesus saves you doesn't that mean you rely on the church having preserved the New Testament to save you?  Again, faulty premise.